# Numpy array to make a 'Z' of 1s and 0s?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Any idea how to solve this question? Am new to python programming :( Thanks!

QUESTION
Given a single positive integer 'n' greater than 2, create a NumPy array of size (n x n) will all zeros and ones such that the ones make a shape like 'Z'.

Examples:

Input 1: `3`, Output 1:

```
[[1 1 1]
 [0 1 0]
 [1 1 1]]
```

Input 2: 5 -- Output 2:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1] 
 [0 0 0 1 0] 
 [0 0 1 0 0] 
 [0 1 0 0 0] 
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? In the spirit of asking good questions on StackOverflow, you'll get better results if you help us help you a bit. 
For example, the first and last rows of the array seem pretty simple. Just a list of 1's N length long. Could you do that part for starters?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that feedback :) Ill keep that in mind for next time! I created the zeros matrix and changes the top and bottom rows to 1's but got stumped as to how to convert the diagonals:(

Answer (score 1):

Let's try `numpy` style:

```
def get_z(n):
    out = np.eye(n, dtype=np.int)
    out[[0,-1]] = 1
    return out[::-1]

get_z(5)
```

---

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Enter size:"))

data = np.zeros([n,n], dtype=int) # fill grid of nxn with zeros.
data[0] = data[n-1] = np.ones(n, dtype=int) # set first and last row to 1s.

j = n-2
for i in range(1,n-1): # fills diagonally 1s.
    data[i][j] = 1
    j-=1

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it totally in Numpy.

So, we will divide the problem into three main parts :

1. Initialize the 2-d nd-array into the appropriate shape (defined by N)
2. Then, fill the main diagonals with 1's (defined by where i == j for nd-arrays [i][j])
3. Finally, flip the elements with left and right indices of the nd-array

-1-

```
import numpy as np
# given input size 
N = 5  
# first initializing with first row as all ones 
rows_of_ones_zeros = np.ones((1, N), int)
# Now, there will be N-2 rows of zeros , and finally one more row of ones.
for i in range(N-2):
   rows_of_ones_zeros = np.concatenate((rows_of_ones_zeros, np.zeros((1, N), int)))
else:
   rows_of_ones_zeros = np.concatenate((rows_of_ones_zeros, np.ones((1, N), int)))
```

-2-

```
# fill the main diagonal elements with 1
np.fill_diagonal(rows_of_ones_zeros, 1)
```

-3-

```
# now, flip it 
rows_of_ones_zeros = np.fliplr(rows_of_ones_zeros)
```

Here, is complete code snippet in one go :
[Complete code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2zd8.jpg)

For better understanding :

- np.zeros : Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with zeros.
- np.ones : Return a new array of given shape and type, filled with ones.
- np.concatenate : Join a sequence of arrays along an existing axis.
- np.fill_diagonal : Fill the main diagonal of the given array of any dimensionality.
- np.fliplr : Flip array in the left/right direction.

(I am sure there might be more better ways of doing this)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np  

n=int(input())  

a=np.zeros((n,n),dtype=int)  

### since to form a "Z", the row + column index adds upto n-1  

for row in range(n):  
   for col in range(n):   
    if row==0 or row ==n-1 or (row+col==n-1):       
           a[row][col]=1          
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
#take input of array size from user.
n = int(input())
#get the array of ones of size (n,n)
array_one = np.ones((n,n),dtype='int')
#from all rows except first and last,for all columns, make value to 0
array_one[1:-1,0:] = 0
#fill the diagonal elements of the array with 1
#help(np.fill_diagonal)
np.fill_diagonal(array_one,1)
#Reverse the order of elements along axis 1 (left/right)
np.fliplr(array_one)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?